# Creating a custom input select in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic, formbuilder

I want to create a custom input for formtasic that uses a custom collection

My collection is returned by `MyModule::Categories.all`

I'm extending SelectInput

```
class CategoriesSelectInput < Formtastic::Inputs::SelectInput
  def select_html
    collection = MyModule::Categories.all
    builder.select(input_name, collection, input_options, input_html_options)
  end
```

end

but the formatting seems to get lost, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late.. but try this way:

```
class CategoriesSelectInput < Formtastic::Inputs::SelectInput
  def to_html
    collection = MyModule::Categories.all

    builder.input input_name, as: :select, collection: collection, input_html: input_html_options

  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to extend select input. Formatstic has awesome support for providing custom collections. Read it's documentation for details: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

In short, you can do something like this:

```
<%= f.input :some_id, :as => :select, :collection => MyModule::Categories.all %>
```

Comment: I know I can do that. but I want to do `<%=  f.input, :something, as: MyCustomSelect %>`